# Android background schedule task not working

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android development. I have created an Android app using Kotlin and I have implemented a background schedule task with WorkManager. During the development everything works fine but when I build an APK file and install the app, the background task does not working. I'm using 'huawei Y5 2018' for testing. I tried some tips like adding the app to the protected apps but this didn't help.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is part of my code:

`implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.4"`

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .build()

            val saveRequest =
                PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UploadWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    .build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(activity!!.applicationContext)
                .enqueue(saveRequest)
```

Comment: I had this kind of problem using xiaomi devices, and that was caused by some energy saving strategies from the vendor. Huawei also has this kind of strategy. Can you try this? https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.digitalcitizen.life/stop-huawei-from-closing-apps-when-you-lock-screen

Comment: Thanks for the good article. I followed the steps but still doesn't work. Is it possible that there is something wrong in code that working in development mode but not after build?

Comment: As soon as I have the opportunity I will try with other device.